# WPF WebBrowser-Control does not display content

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

in my WPF-Application, I use a WebBrowser-Control to display Web contents. I test it with the Google search. In the following, first some source code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
       <WebBrowser x:Name="browser"
                            Width="494"
                            Height="293"
                            Canvas.Left="3"
                            Canvas.Top="162"/>

</Canvas>
```

```
public EventSide()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.de/"));
}
```

Now it depends on the following issues:
The contents of the WebBrowser control is completely empty. I'm going with the mouse over the WebBrowser Control, changes at the top and the mouse-cursor to the text cursor and I get a Tooltip called search. This is the search field from the google page. This means that the information is available from the Web via my webbrowser control, but apparently can not be displayed.

In my main window, I set the AllowsTransparency-property to "True". If I reset it to "False", the contents are displayed in my web browser element. Since I need a separate window design, I am dependent on the AllowsTransparency property.

Had anyone ever had the same problem and has a proposed solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess WebBrowser control is not loaded when you call navigate, try this

```
public EventSide()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browser.Loaded += delegate
    {
        browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.de/"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that WebBrowser is old style(COM I guess) control and doesn't support styling, animating and AllowTransparency...

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx) for more details

I think the only solution is to use 3rd part browsers like [WPF 3D Chromium Browser](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/wpf-3d-chromium-browser/) if you really need it

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your post.

Unfortunately, it did not help.

I also tried using a button handler, to load a new page in my WebBrowser Control. Even that does not work. When I reset the AllowsTransparency-property in my MainWindow to "False", will it works.

Comment: Try to make working this sample http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/08/18/wpf-webbrowser-control-sample.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your Sample run. When I am set the Window-propertie "AllowsTransparency" to true, I have the same problem. The Content isn´t visible.

Comment: Ohhh, I see now, I forgot to say... No WebBrowser control doesn't support AllowTransparency, because it is old style control... see edited psot

Comment: @Matapolo mark as answers posts that help you, or no one will answer you in the future

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Have you found a solution by any chance?

Comment: Did you try subscribing event?